# SSL error with Rubygems (unable to connect)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ssl, openssl, rubygems

I've installed a fresh version of `ruby 2.3.3` via RVM and I'm attempting to install rails (`gem install rails`) however, when I do I receive the following error:

ERROR:  Could not find a valid gem 'rails' (>= 0), here is why:
                Unable to download data from https://rubygems.org/ - SSL_connect returned=1 errno=0 state=error: certificate verify failed (https://api.rubygems.org/specs.4.8.gz)

I have followed the instructions on the SSL cert page on [rubygem](http://guides.rubygems.org/ssl-certificate-update) to no avail. Every cert I can find within rubygems seems to match the most recent version.

I have also run `gem update --system` and receive the following error:

```
ERROR:  While executing gem ... (Gem::RemoteFetcher::FetchError)
        SSL_connect returned=1 errno=0 state=error: certificate verify failed (https://api.rubygems.org/specs.4.8.gz)

Lastly, here is the output of `gem env`:

 RubyGems Environment:
  - RUBYGEMS VERSION: 2.5.2
  - RUBY VERSION: 2.3.3 (2016-11-21 patchlevel 222) [x86_64-darwin14]
  - INSTALLATION DIRECTORY: /Users/adammay/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.3
  - USER INSTALLATION DIRECTORY: /Users/adammay/.gem/ruby/2.3.0
  - RUBY EXECUTABLE: /Users/adammay/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.3/bin/ruby
  - EXECUTABLE DIRECTORY: /Users/adammay/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.3/bin
  - SPEC CACHE DIRECTORY: /Users/adammay/.gem/specs
  - SYSTEM CONFIGURATION DIRECTORY: /Users/adammay/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.3/etc
  - RUBYGEMS PLATFORMS:
    - ruby
    - x86_64-darwin-14
  - GEM PATHS:
     - /Users/adammay/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.3
     - /Users/adammay/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.3@global
  - GEM CONFIGURATION:
     - :update_sources => true
     - :verbose => true
     - :backtrace => false
     - :bulk_threshold => 1000
     - "gem" => "--no-ri --no-rdoc"
  - REMOTE SOURCES:
     - https://rubygems.org/
  - SHELL PATH:
     - /Users/adammay/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.3/bin
     - /Users/adammay/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.3@global/bin
     - /Users/adammay/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.3/bin
     - /Users/adammay/.rvm/bin
     - /Applications/Postgres.app/Contents/Versions/9.4/bin
     - /usr/local
     - /usr/local/bin
     - /usr/local/sbin
     - /usr/bin
     - /usr/local/bin
     - /usr/bin
     - /bin
     - /usr/sbin
     - /sbin
```

Comment: this repo helped me figure out what was wrong with the ssl-setup on my machine: https://github.com/mislav/ssl-tools

or this: https://github.com/rvm/rvm/blob/master/help/osx-ssl-certs.md

Answer (score 0):

You can try to do this, it can fix your problems.

```
gem update --system --source http://rubygems.org/
```

Now you're ready to use `gem update` and `gem install rails`

Comment: you should think long and hard about this "workaround". throwing your hands in the air and turn off ssl may not be the thing you want to do

Comment: @SaschaKaestle I agree, but what would be the real solution then? I'm searching for it right now, but no immediate solution pops up.