# Gem - Connection reset by peer - SSL_connect

Tags: rubygems

I'm trying to install Ruby on Rails on my machine.

Every time I run:

```
 sudo gem install rails
```

The terminal returns

```
ERROR:  Could not find a valid gem 'rails' (>= 0), here is why:
      Unable to download data from https://rubygems.org/ -         
Errno::ECONNRESET: Connection reset by peer - SSL_connect 
(https://api.rubygems.org/specs.4.8.gz)
```

How can I solve this?

Comment: See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37253021/could-not-find-a-valid-gem-rhc-ssl-connect-server-certificate-verify-failed-o) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40834691/ssl-error-with-rubygems-unable-to-connect) for related questions.